# regular expression to avoid complete match

Tags: regex, jmeter

I want to extract the `id` and `type` of the objects (e.g. Regions and Countries) where `available=true`. I used regular expression `{"name":".+?","id":"(.+?)","type":"(.+?)","available":true`.

I'm getting a complete row starting from *name ...{other stuff in the middle}... available =true* which includes other ids/names even where `available=false` as well.

Sample data below

```
{  
 "error":null,
 "data":{  
   "airports":[],
   "pocs":[],
   "regions":[  
     {  
        "name":"Central America",
        "id":"L04305",
        "type":"CruiseArea",
        "available":false,
        "countries":"Mexico",
        "group":null
     },
     {  
        "name":"Caribbean",
        "id":"L04304",
        "type":"CruiseArea",
        "available":false,
        "countries":"St Maarten,Barbados,British Virgin Islands,St Kitts and Nevis,St Vincent and the Grenadines,Antigua",
        "group":null
     },
     {  
        "name":"Western Mediterranean",
        "id":"L34381",
        "type":"CruiseArea",
        "available":true,
        "countries":"Spain",
        "group":null
     },
     {  
        "name":"Eastern Mediterranean",
        "id":"L34373",
        "type":"CruiseArea",
        "available":false,
        "countries":"Greece,Italy,Slovenia,Montenegro,Croatia",
        "group":null
     },
     {  
        "name":"North Africa And Middle East",
        "id":"L04301",
        "type":"CruiseArea",
        "available":false,
        "countries":"Morocco",
        "group":null
     },
     {  
        "name":"Fjords, Iceland And Arctic",
        "id":"L34384",
        "type":"CruiseArea",
        "available":true,
        "countries":"Norway",
        "group":null
     },
     {  
        "name":"Northern Europe And UK",
        "id":"L34383",
        "type":"CruiseArea",
        "available":true,
        "countries":"United Kingdom",
        "group":null
     }
  ],
  "countries":[  
     {  
        "name":"Spain",
        "id":"ESP",
        "type":"COUNTRY",
        "available":true,
        "countries":null,
        "group":null
     },
     {  
        "name":"Jamaica",
        "id":"JAM",
        "type":"COUNTRY",
        "available":false,
        "countries":null,
        "group":null
     },
     {  
        "name":"Greece",
        "id":"GRC",
        "type":"COUNTRY",
        "available":false,
        "countries":null,
        "group":null
     },
     {  
        "name":"Italy",
        "id":"ITA",
        "type":"COUNTRY",
        "available":false,
        "countries":null,
        "group":null
     },
     {  
        "name":"Turkey",
        "id":"TUR",
        "type":"COUNTRY",
        "available":false,
        "countries":null,
        "group":null
     },
     {  
        "name":"Barbados",
        "id":"BRB",
        "type":"COUNTRY",
        "available":false,
        "countries":null,
        "group":null
     },
     {  
        "name":"Mexico",
        "id":"MEX",
        "type":"COUNTRY",
        "available":false,
        "countries":null,
        "group":null
     },
     {  
        "name":"Israel",
        "id":"ISR",
        "type":"COUNTRY",
        "available":false,
        "countries":null,
        "group":null
     },
     {  
        "name":"Cuba",
        "id":"CUB",
        "type":"COUNTRY",
        "available":false,
        "countries":null,
        "group":null
     },
     {  
        "name":"Croatia",
        "id":"HRV",
        "type":"COUNTRY",
        "available":false,
        "countries":null,
        "group":null
     }
    ],
    "itineraries":[],
    "airportGroups":[]
  },
 "nomatch":false,
 "durations":null,
 "searchError":null
}
```

Comment: Use `[^"]+` instead of `.+?`

Comment: Rather use a json parser like https://github.com/stig/json-framework

Comment: hi..thanks..i got what i wanted on using [^"]+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution (without a total re-write) could be

```
{"name":"[^"]*","id":"([^"]*)","type":"([^"]*)","available":true,[^{}]*}
```

Instead of scanning for `.` - any character but newline - scan for any character but `{` or `}` - `[^{}]`.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wI9uF3/4).

Comment: can u please explain me how does this work?

Comment: Check the explanation at regex101. It's pretty thorough.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going for [JSON Path PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor) available from JMeter 3.0 release as it is more suitable for working with JSON data.

The relevant JSON Path Expressions would be:

- `$..[?(@.available == true)].id`
- `$..[?(@.available == true)].type`

Demo:

[image: JSON Path PostProcessor Demo]

References:

- [JSONPath - XPath for JSON](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)
- [Advanced Usage of the JSON Path Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)